# Select rows where all children contain same value only and no other scenario

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am writing a query to select all rows where all children contain same value only and no other scenario.

Tried many examples online, nothing matching.

select * from table where all children contain same value only and no other scenario. Must contain at-least one child to be returned.

- Children are mapped by an ID to the parent.
- Children value is one column, it can be int or null. Let's say all children must contain the value of 5 and nothing else to be included. Will not work if most children contain 5, it has to be only parents where all children are 5 only.
- Parent may have multiple children
- Parent may have no children (in this case, do not include in results)

Example parents:

```
A(id: 1), B(id: 2), C(id: 3), D(id: 4), E(id: 5).
children id mapping: AAA, BB, CCCCC, E
children values: 
A:5, A:5, A:3
B:5, B:null
C:5, C:5, C:5, C:5, C:5
E:null
```

Then the only parent that would return is C since all of C's children contain 5 only.

You see that A would not work because one of A's children contains a 3 and must all be 5's.
You see that B does not return because one of B's children contains null and not all 5's.

Comment: Data in a *text table* format would really help.  Setting up a db fiddle of some sort would at least allow others to understand your data structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your data structure is:

```
parentid   childid   value
```

Then you can do what you want with aggregation:

```
select parentid
from t
group by parentid
having min(value) = max(value) and  -- all values are the  same
       min(value) = 5               -- and that value is 5
```

If `value` can be `NULL` and you want to avoid that, also include:

```
 count(value) = count(*)
```

Comment: This will also return 'B' containing `NULL` as value.

Comment: Thank you! Amazingly fast answer.